# How to implement a Waiting for GPS?

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm trying to implement a "Waiting for GPS" method like the one below, which will show up whenever there is no GPS, like when the GPS lock gets lost or simply initializing the GPS lock...

[image: waiting for gps]

I've already implemented a simple LocationListener and it's working correctly, but I want something more user-friendly.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936662/waiting-for-gps-fix-dialog-box-throws-bad-token-exception-android?rq=1) SO but it looks like it is implemented a bit bad...

Comment: So you want help displaying something like the image above? Do you already have the code which waits for a signal?

Comment: I'm looking for the code which waits for a signal, the rest I have knowledge on how to do it... I thought of a `Runnable`, is it a proper way of achieving this?

Comment: simply update the UI once `onLocationChanged` is called

Comment: and that leads me to the part that when the location is lost... I want it to display a small message saying something like `GPS Signal Lost... Reconnecting`